# Rendering json from two models in Rails index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to render json in an index method that joins data from a foreign-key related table in Rails. I have a model that has user_id as a foreign key.

```
class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

I am then rendering that table and exposing the **user_id** field.

```
def index
    panels = Batch.where("user_id = #{current_user.id} or (user_id <> #{current_user.id} and public_panel = true)")
    render json: panels,  only: [:id, :description, :name, :public_panel, :updated_at, :user_id], root: false
end
```

What I would like to do is to somehow expose the users name, which is on the **Users** model. ie: **user_id.user_name**

**EDIT**

From reading documentation, I think I need to use **include** but would also like to alias one of the fields. I have a field called **name** in both tables.

Something is wrong with this **include**

```
  def index
    panels = Batch.include([:users]).where("user_id = #{current_user.id} or (user_id <> #{current_user.id} and public_panel = true)")
    render json: panels,  only: [:id, :name, :description, :public_panel, :updated_at, :user_id], root: false
  end
```

**EDIT2**

Thank you @Paritosh Piplewar ... I am getting some errors with the syntax. To complicate matters the field I am after is **user.name**, not **user.user_name**. This will conflict with **batches.name**, so I need to alias it.

```
Started GET "/api/batches" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-08-13 15:39:03 +0200

SyntaxError (/home/assay/assay/app/controllers/api/batches_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
              user: { only: :first_name }, 
                   ^
/home/assay/assay/app/controllers/api/batches_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
              user: { only: :first_name }, 
                                          ^
/home/assay/assay/app/controllers/api/batches_controller.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end):
```

**EDIT 3**

The original question has been answered, but the json returned is like this

```
data: [{"id"=>1306, "updated_at"=>Wed, 13 Aug 2014 12:37:23 UTC +00:00, "description"=>"asc", "user_id"=>1, "public_panel"=>true, "user"=>{"name"=>"Joe Bloggs"}}, {"id"=>1307,
```

This bit is causing problems for my Angular.js front-end.

```
"user"=>{"name"=>"Joe Bloggs"}}
```

Comment: you can delegate user name in batch model

Comment: Thanks @AnilMaurya how would I do that?

Comment: Side note: it can be super unsafe to use string interpolation in your database queries. Instead use `?` substitution to have your values properly quoted to prevent SQL injection like so: `where("user_id = ? or (user_id <> ? and public_panel = true)", current_user.id, current_user.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom method and do it. Something like this

```
class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def user_name
    user.name
  end

end
```

Now, in controller you can simply do this

```
def index
    panels = Batch.where("user_id = ? or (user_id <> ? and public_panel = true)", current_user.id, current_user.id)
    data = panels.as_json(methods: :user_name, 
                only: [:id, :description, :public_panel, :updated_at, :user_id, :user_name],
                root: false) 
    render json: data
end
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had to make a small change: the root: false within the panels.as_json was ignored... so I removed it and added render json: data, root: false and it works fine.

Comment: Great. be sure of `n+1` query. if there is,you might have to `preload` it. Also, if you think something is missed, feel free to update this answer accordingly. I haven't tried it, just wrote as per documentation so there might be some silly mistake. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

i assume you mean `user.user_name`

this is how you can do it

```
def index
    panels = Batch.where("user_id = #{current_user.id} or (user_id <> #{current_user.id} and public_panel = true)")
    data = panels.as_json(include: 
                {user: { only: :name }}, 
                only: [:id, :description, :public_panel, :updated_at, :user_id],
                root: false) 
    render json: data
end
```

Comment: give a try now. just simple `hash` thing

Comment: Kind of working, I guess the original question has been answered. See edit 3.

Answer (score 1):

For more complex json views than just redering a single model, I'd tell you to use jbuilder. Jbuilder is now part of the rails framework.

It's as easy as

1. Remove render line and make panels an instance variavle (@panels)
2. Create a index.json.jbuilder file under app/views/api/batches
3. Create the view you want

```
json.array @panels do |panel|
    panel.(panel, 
      :id, 
      :description, 
      :public_panel, 
      :user_id, 
      :updated_at
    )

    json.user panel.user.user_name
end
```